# How can I view the definition of a Web Application?

Tags: web-application

I'm hoping this isn't too stupid, but I'm trying to set up a basic Web Application in Server 2010 and want to crib settings from another environment to make sure I'm configuring everything correctly. (I'm setting up a basic application for use by a TFS installation.) However, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to view the settings that were used to create the application (service account, database, etc.)

I'm in the admin console, with the application selected, and I can now manage all sorts of things, but all I want is to see the creation parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://WebApp
$wa.ContentDatabases
$wa.IisSettings.Values
$wa.ApplicationPool
```

That should hopefully get you started.  You can do $wa | gm to see other values you can pick out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try SharePoint Manager 2010. You can view all the information about the web application, site Collection, etc based on that Tool.
Download the SharePoint Manager 2010 from here, http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438

Comment: Thanks. Looks interesting, but I'm reluctant to run new code on a box which is being set up for production.